# Why return string& from a const method won't compile?

Tags: c++, string, reference, constants

Given the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class A
{
private:
    string m_name;
    string m_first;
public:
    A(): m_first("string") {}
    virtual void print() const {}
    string& getName() const {return m_first;}  // won't compile 
    const string& getLastName() const {return m_name;}  // compile
};


int main()
{
    A a;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler presents : `"invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::string&' from expression of type 'const std::string'"` 
Why can't I return "m_first" from getName() ? I thought that the const on the tail of the function states that the function will not change 'this'... but I'm not trying to change this , just return a data member.

Answer (score 15):

Because inside a const method, all non-`mutable` members are implicitly `const`. So, you're trying to bind a reference to non-const `std::string` (your return value) to an  object of type `const std::string`, which is illegal(because it would allow modification of const data), hence the error.

Comment: If it let you do this, then the calling function could change your member data. Not the intent of marking a function const.

Comment: @crashmstr: I don't understand - did I write something that contradicts to your (correct) statement?

Comment: @Ron_s: if this was possible you could for example, do this: `a.getName() = "foo";` and it would change the m_first member.

Comment: @Armen: No! You have a great answer. I was just stating the practical reasoning behind the implicit const-ness.

Answer (score 6):

By returning a reference, you are saying you can modify the class data-member that the reference-variable is implicitly pointing to, and therefore modify the class ... but you have dedicated the class method as a constant method, meaning it is not allowed to change any class member variables that have not been specifically declared mutable. So by returning a non-constant reference, you are breaking the encapsulation "contract" that the class interface has established.  Your options are to either return a temporary object (i.e., that creates a copy of the object), or a constant-reference.  So you could either do

```
const string& getName() const {return m_first;}
```

or

```
string getName() const { return m_first; } //copies m_first and returns the copy
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code promises that the reference won't change the m_name member, but you return a reference that *can* change it. What you want is a string const& return type.

This returns a "read-only" reference to m_name.

See also: [the C++ FAQ on const correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.11)

Answer (score 2):

When you return `string &`, it allows modifying class member... but the function is `const`, so it is not allowed to allow such a situation. But when you return `const string &`, it doesn't allow modifying class instance.

Answer (score 1):

What if you call `A.getName().ModifyTheString()` ==> this means you modified `this`.